# If Possible to Read existing PDF content position and add the some content after over the existing content in laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, fpdf, fpdi

Laravel Package:
"setasign/fpdi": "^2.3",
"setasign/fpdf": "^1.8"

```
$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi('L','mm','A4');
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile(public_path().'/'.$url);
$pdf->setFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
for($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++){
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pageDimensions = $pdf->getImportedPageSize($tplIdx);
    $pdf->addPage($pageDimensions['orientation'], $pageDimensions);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
 }
```

If It Possible read the content of the last page and get after page content ordinate of the current position. then Write new content without add new page or whitespaces

Comment: basically you want to append to previous pdf

Comment: yes, I have need the last line of position.

Comment: FPDI doesn't support access to pages content.

Comment: But in this code pageCount is work properly, Just need the last line position and then after write new content

Comment: "last line position" is (if I understand correct) an information resolved by rendering the text of the imported page. That's not supported by FPDI.

Comment: @JanSlabon you have an idea of a supported PHP library?   so please tell me

Comment: Nothing related to FPDI. But in combination with our [SetaPDF-Extractor](https://setasign.com/extractor) (not free!) there may be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Pdf Generate using DomPdf so you can generate HTML file using

```
$pdf->getDomPDF()->outputHtml()
```

Generated html file using DomPDF add some element like this:

`<div id="divId"></div>`

Then whenever you need to edit this document, you need to read the HTML file line by line and
Edit document:

```
$url=public_path() .'/test.html';
$htmlFile='';
foreach(file($url) as  $key => $line){
  if(strpos($line, 'id="divId"') !== false){
    $line='<div>Hello world</div>';
  }
  $htmlFile.=$line;
}
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($htmlFile)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
$pdf->output();
```